# Output x if it is weekend

Tags: javascript

I have created this to check if time is between *17:00* / *23:00*.
This works fine! But now I want to check if its weekend.

Can you help me?

```
var objDate = new Date();
var hours = objDate.getHours();
if (hours >= 17 && hours <= 23) {
   document.write('<!--test1 -->');
}
else {
   document.write('<!--test2 -->');
}
```

Comment: [Date.prototype.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `getDay()` [method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) of the Date object (0 corresponds to Sunday and 6 to Saturday):

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    var objDate = new Date();
    var hours = objDate.getHours(),
    dayOfWeek = objDate.getDay();
    if(hours >= 17 && hours <= 23 && (dayOfWeek == 6 || dayOfWeek == 0)){
       document.write('<!--test1 -->');
    } else {
       document.write('<!--test2 -->');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       var objDate = new Date();
        var hours = objDate.getHours();
        var n = objDate.getDay(); 
        if(hours >= 17 && hours <= 23){
          alert('<!--test1 -->');
        }
        else{
          alert('<!--test2 -->');
        }

        if(n == 0 || n == 6)
        {
        alert('Weekend');
        }
        else
        {
        alert('Weekday');
        }
```